Dockerized Etherpad behind nginx reverse proxy returns 404 when accessed via subdomain
so I've set up an Etherpad instance on a server running Ubuntu 24.04. The setup utilizes the default docker-compose setup that Etherpad provides in their repository.
Furthermore, because I am using the instance with friends and dislike telling non-technical people about how to connect to specific ports such as :9001 (and also for convenience, who likes remembering numbers?) I've decided to set up an nginx reverse proxy server who redirects all traffic going to a specific subdomain to port 9001 where the Etherpad docker container listens.
Now for the fun part.
After finally getting all the routing and proxying to work, I'm slightly confused about a problem that has arised. Apparently when connecting to the instance via my subdomain, I get correctly forwarded to the front page, but as I try to access a Pad that I know exists, I get a 404 and the white page with black text telling me "Cannot GET /p/[PAD_NAME]"Additionally, when trying to create a new pad (I thought it could be that the pad name contained a / and that this would probably break nginx, so I created one with only alphanumeric letters), it seems to get stuck in kind of a "dead load", with nothing happening for a long enough time to be concerning.
Now I can safely say that this is a configuration error in my nginx config, but I haven'T yet figured out what exactly causes this. I know it isn't the Etherpad instance, because connecting via mydomain:9001 serves it perfectly, I can create new pads, and access the specific pad I cannot access via the subdomain.
nginx proxy config for the relevant subdomain currently looks like this:
server {

        server_name [SUBDOMAIN];

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_redirect default;
        }

        error_log /var/log/nginx/pad-error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/pad-access.log;

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[SUBDOMAIN]/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[SUBDOMAIN]/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

I've been trying around with the different proxy options, adding new ones, removing old ones. The current one is mnore or less copied from a working one I found here, but well, doesn'T seem to work for me.
My guess is that it has got something to do with the HTTP to HTTPS upgrade, I am using Certbot (as seen in the config) to manage my certificates.
Thankful for every little pointer, as I don't even know anymore what to look for!
